# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer exclude fields by key

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have a class which I do not have control over it's source:

```
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
    private SomeField someFiled; // Not serializable
    ... // Some other fields that are serializable
}
```

So this class is not fully `Serializable`, and I am running into `StackOverflowError` when I try to serialize it as json using Spring Boot as `@ResponseBody`.

I have two controller methods:

```
@ResponseBody public SomeClassImpl get();

@ResponseBody public SomeOtherClass find();
```

I have control over the source of `SomeOtherClass` which includes `SomeClass` as a property.

I could not figure out how to ignore a field using `@JsonIgnore` annotation, I probably need to to control the source.What I can do with annotations is that I can ignore `SomeClass` property from `SomeOtherClass` which does not help the first method above. So I decided to implement `JsonSerializer<SomeClassImpl>`:

```
@Override
public void serialize(SomeClassImpl someClass, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // I need to write all fields except some
}
```

Or can I handle this with annotations? If yes how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modifying the source code is not an option, you can use *mix-in annotations* to add [Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to a bean.

First define a mix-in annotation interface or class:

```java
public interface FooMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    Object getBiz();
}
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use the defined interface as a mix-in for your POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(Foo.class, FooMixIn.class);
```

---

- All [annotation sets](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) that Jackson recognizes can be mixed in.
- All kinds of annotations (member method, static method, field, constructor annotations) can be mixed in.
- Only method (and field) name and signature are used for matching annotations: access definitions (`private`, `protected`, ...) and method implementations are ignored.

---

For more details, have a look at the Jackson [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you read the part where I mention why I cannot use annotations, or am I missing something?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Please read my answer one more time. Mix-ins allow you to add annotation to a bean without modifying its source code.

Comment: I think I have been missing something, I am giving it a try at the moment. Will update soon, thanks for the follow-up, I appreciate it.